# How to stream screen from two phones to one video?

Tags: lenovo, streaming, asus-zenfone-2

I am trying to do a Challenge with my friend, (who gots faster to arena4 in Clash royale) and I need to stream from two phones in one video. I have computer and Asus Zenfone ZE551ML (mine) and Lenovo A536 (from that phone will be streamed friends' screen). Can you help me? I also have additional wi-fi receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [a vnc server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.abr.android.avnc.beta) on each phone, and use a vnc viewer on your computer to connect to both the phones. You could then just record your computer screen.